# template specialization

Tags: c++

```
template<class T> struct ISocket
{
    void connect(){}
    void raw_socket(){}
};

template <class SocketType, class Arg1,class Arg2>
struct ISocket< SocketType(Arg1,Arg2) > 
{
    typedef SocketType socket_type;
    typedef Arg1 arg_type;
    typedef Arg2 arg_type2;

    socket_type* raw_socket_;

    ISocket():raw_socket_(&SocketType()){}


    socket_type& raw_socket(){return *raw_socket_;}


    void connect()
    {
        raw_socket_->connect();
    } 
};
```

why I am obliged to define template struct ISocket; ? THe code below doesn't compile under VS2010, when you try to use ISocket and call connect for instance

```
template<class T> struct ISocket;

template <class SocketType, class Arg1,class Arg2>
struct ISocket< SocketType(Arg1,Arg2) > 
{
    typedef SocketType socket_type;
    typedef Arg1 arg_type;
    typedef Arg2 arg_type2;

    socket_type* raw_socket_;

    ISocket():raw_socket_(&SocketType()){}


    socket_type& raw_socket(){return *raw_socket_;}


    void connect()
    {
        ref_raw_socket_->connect();
    } 
};
```

I call with this code :

```
struct SocketTcp
{
    void setup(std::string ip,int port)
    {
        std::cout << ip.c_str() << " " << port << "\n";
    }

    void connect()
    {

    }
};


typedef ISocket< SocketTcp(std::string, int) > Socket;

int main()
{

    ISocket<Socket> s;

    s.connect();
    s.raw_socket(); 
}
```

Comment: Um, why can't you do what instead? What is it about the second version you want to do, and what prevents you from doing it? Ask a (textual) question, don't just post code. We're not a diff tool, and we're not a compiler.

Comment: with visual 2010, if i don't give a definition of template<class T> struct ISocket; that don't compile. And why downvote this, are you serious ?!

Comment: ... and even if we were a compiler, we would not parse that input.

Comment: @Guillaume: I would guess that the downvote was because you didn't specify *what the problem was*...

Comment: ok don't understand your comment, I can tell you that this code doesn't compil under visual 2010, if you try to use ISocket class and call connect.

Comment: @Oli OK I see sorry if i was not clear

Comment: What do you expect as a `SocketType` template argument?

Comment: @Xeo I have edited twice to add call site

Comment: Too much code, but too little explanation about the problem faced. An introduction would be good. Just saying *it doesn't compil* do not help to find why or what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>First, `ref_raw_socket_->connect();`. You don't have a member `ref_raw_socket_`, only `raw_socket_`.</strike>
Second, you initialize it to a **temporary** `SocketType()`. After your constructor, that object is destroyed, not there anymore, and your pointer is now a *dangling pointer* and it is undefined behaviour if you use it.
<strike>Third, what do you expect as a template argument for your `ISocket`?</strike>
**Edit**
This `ISocket<Socket> s;` makes no sense in regard to your typedef. You use your `ISocket` as an argument for your `ISocket`? If I change the call site to this:

```
typedef ISocket< SocketTcp(std::string, int) > Socket;

int main(){
    Socket s;
//  ^^^^^^ not ISocket<Socket>

    s.connect();
    s.raw_socket(); 
}
```

And change the constructor to this (and add a destructor):

```
ISocket()
    : raw_socket_(new SocketType())
{}

~ISocket(){
    delete raw_socket_;
}
```

The code compiles just fine with no errors. For why I use `new`, see my second point before the edit.

Comment: This would be so much better as a comment.

Comment: @The Guy: Yeah, the first revision would have been, but not anymore. :) And you can't really format your code with newlines in comments.

Comment: ok Thanks Xeo, I am very tired, and I write very bad code. Thanks for your answer all is OK now